# 555 circuit acting weirdly

Tags: 555

In essense, whatI have are four 555s (2x556) One is a 0.5 s monostable,the other a 147 Hz tone generator. The other is a (30 s) monostable, and a 0.3 s astable.

If I run the 0.3 s astable on its own, (disconnect diodes) it runs fine. I have the reset tied to ground via a relay coil which disables the astable. Place VCC on the high side of relay, and it is enabled as planned.

The other part of the circuit was originally a 30 s timer, but it would cut off after about 1.5 s despite a 150 kΩ and 470 uF cap.

So I  changed the circuit a little so the threshold was grounded via 100 kΩ. Now when triggered, it should stay on indefinitely.

However, the problem arise trying to connect the two parts.

Again, my theory says that the high output of the monostable should power the relay and present a high to the reset pin.
That's when it chops off at 1.5 s. (Why it is 1.5 s when there are no timing components with that RC period is also a mystery; I have tried 4700 uF as a supply decouple, but it makes no difference.)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmDUHt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The GND to relay top is a protection diode, and the other was suggested to stop the circuit "locking up".

The relay is a FRS-1 with a coil value of 320 Ω.

(Maybe the reset is being pulled low? But I thought the top of the coil should be at the voltage of the 556 output)

** I have shown two 555's in diagram as there is no 556 on Circuit Lab. But the 556 IS two 555 chips anyway !

Comment: I'm not sure if the 555's output is strong enough to drive the relay coil...

Comment: @aschipfl I'm certain that even if it happens to be, it's not something you *should* do. Also, having four 555s would under normal circumstances be a clear indication you should have zero 555s and one cheap microcontroller.

Comment: What is the supply voltage, and how are you providing it? Battery?

Comment: also, your modifications (the 100 kΩ resistors) don't appear in your circuit? It'd be much less ambiguous if they did!

Comment: I'm not really following your description of what you think it's doing wrong, but you definitely need  a series resistor for the LED D1 and U1 may not like having the reset pulled below ground momentarily.

Comment: Your first paragraph describe four 555 functions.  However, U2 on your schematic is *none* of them.  What is it you are trying to achieve?  What are your inputs, and what are your expected outputs for each input combination?  Make a table for clarity.

Comment: It was for  a charity event, and I didn;t have the time to buy in /program Arduino, which would make like easier. Yes,I said 4x555 as effectively a 556 chip IS two 555's back to back ! Supply voltage will be 10xAA batts, (12v) curently 2x9v batts for tests. Yes, I have added an LED resistor. I just did the diagram too quickly.

Comment: What am I expecting? As per circuit, button is pushed, output goes high turning on relay, and giving a high to the reset pin of the other half of the 556, (the second half / 555 shown in diagram) This astable then gives a 0.3 squarewave that is used to clock components not shown -ie a 4017 But in practice, the circuit as shown, the astable stops running after 1.5 secs

Comment: Your diagram shows a normally-closed pushbutton, so the output of U2 will be high from the get-go. If that's yet another error/omission in your schematic, NOW is the time to go in and edit it so that it reflects reality. There is no excuse for leaving errors in a diagram.

Comment: @aschipfl a 555 can totally power a relay in the right circumstances,  If this circuit is designed for 5V then probably not,  but 12V  relays use much less current and most will be fine.

Comment: Corrected the pushbutton and resistor;bear in mind I rushed as I hoped to solve it by Friday eve deadline (I didn't) I also ran into a secondary problem. My 4017 outputs were sent to ULA2003 Darlington drivers to power the LED's.I should have realised, but you can't power a Darlington from a high / low output pin, and need a resistor between the two. Now I have more time,will follow suggestion above, and use Arduino Nanno and Tinkercad simulator.

Comment: (Before someone states there is no 4017 shown in diagram, that part was not causing the prob, and I couldn't really show the 4x555,1x 4017 and 2x ULA2003 7 output darlington driver chips and sound card chip in the online schematic !)